# Soap 1.2 content type issue in nusoap

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I'm working on a PHP (Cake PHP) based web application and using nusoap to send request and get response from the WSDL ( the web service is in .net framework and the Soap version is 1.2 ).

I have to set

```
content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'** ,
```

but nusoap only sending content type `'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'`. 
Please help me out , to set content type `'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'` in nusoap.

*NB : I have so far done:

```
$client = new 
nusoap_client($wsdl,true,array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client->decode_utf8 = false;
```

but the content type is not changing to `'application/soap+xml;'`

Thanks in advance for your help.